# Koa 404 when calling from Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, koa

I am trying to build an app with Koa and Nuxt. this is what I have:

Define service to retrieve from firestore:

```
    const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

    const getItems = () => {

        const db = new Firestore({
            projectId: '*******',
            keyFilename: "******"
        });

        db.collection('items').get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                return snapshot;
            })
    }
```

Define them in `routes.js`:

```
    const Router = require('@koa/router');
    const articleService = require('./services/itemservice');
    const router = new Router();

    router.get('/getitems', async(ctx, next) => {
        ctx.body = articleService.getItems();
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Add routes to retrieve from `routes.js`:

```
    app.use(router.routes());
    app.use(router.allowedMethods());
```

And finally call it from a component:

```
  let articles = axios.get('/getitems')
                  .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                  })//.....
```

I am receiving this error:

```
 response:
   { status: 404,
     statusText: 'Not Found',
     headers:
      { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=us-ascii',
        server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
        date: 'Fri, 25 Oct 2019 16:08:00 GMT',
        connection: 'close',
        'content-length': '315' },
     config:
      { url: '/getarticles',
        method: 'get',
        headers: [Object],
        transformRequest: [Array],
        transformResponse: [Array],
        timeout: 0,
        adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        data: undefined },
     request:
      ClientRequest {
        _header:
         'GET /getitems HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nHost: localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/getitems',
        _ended: true,
        res: [IncomingMessage],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Writable],
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data:
      '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n' },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function] }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've never built an app with Nuxt, but I'll try to help you anyway.

First, I recommend you to read about Promises: 
 - https://github.com/leonardomso/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md 
 - https://github.com/leonardomso/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch8.md 
(those are two chapters of a good `JS` book series!)

Second, you can try two things in order to find the bug: 
 - add a `.catch` block to your thenables, to check if something went wrong; 
 - add a dummy route that just logs an 'OK', to make sure the routes are be registered and up to respond.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: I have the catch in the code. I didn't copy the code but it is there. I think the error `status: 404..` has something to do with how build and register the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my nuxt / express.js app:
If you would try to type in your browser `yourURL/getitems` your nuxt app will try to route you to that page instead of just to show u the data.

First thing to do, how to say,  you need to define what url your backend should handle.
You go to your `nuxt.config.js` and add this line of code:

```
serverMiddleware: ["~/api/index.js"],
```

That means you have a folder called `api` and in that folder you have an `index.js` file and thats your express.js / koa app.

Now in your `index.js` where your express.js / koa app is you need to add at the end of the line this peace of code:

```
module.exports = {
   path: "/api",
   handler: app
};
```

If everything works fine your URL should have now a prefix `api` and you should be able to get the data with `localhost:PORT/api/getitems`

Now nuxt wont try to route you to your `url/api` because it knows now that this is your backend

If you could provide me your folder structure of your nuxt app i could help you more.

Here is more information about `serverMiddleware`

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware

EDIT:

somewhere you have a Folder, lets say ist named `server` or `api`

in that Folder there should be a `index.js` file and your routes, model, Controllers etc.

Lets say you have a Folder called `server` and in that Server you have `index.js` that should look something like this

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
Import routes from "./routes.js"

app.use(routes)

//here you define now your backend path
module.exports = {
   //you can use any path you want
   path: "/backend",
   handler: app
};
app.listen(3000);
```

Now you Need to go to your `nuxt.config.js` file and Point to that `index.js` File

```
 serverMiddleware: ["~/server/index.js"]
```

Now you can Access your data with axios:

```
 axios.get("/backend/getitems").then(data => { console.log(data) })
```

You will Need to add `backend` to your axios url because thats the path you defined that your Server will handle.

Comment: Hello and thanks. I still have a doubt. This is the [index.js file](https://gist.github.com/vherasme/4e1a0ebf79284db4e210ed569f7bd5c5) generated when you create the `Nuxt / Koa` project. How can I apply your suggestion there? Specifically the `module.exports...`

Comment: i have made an edit. i dont know exactly how to add it in a generated koa file. i use express and i didnt generate my express.js file. i have done it on my hand